# Swift Version 2 Running Wolf App Issues

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

[image: Running Wolf App]

I'm having some issues running an App using Swift v2.  Stopping the tmrRun is one issue.  I know how to [tmrRun invalidate] in Objective C but not in Swift v2. Any help would be appreciated.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var imvWolf: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var btnGo: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var btnStop: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var sliSpeed: UISlider!
    var pic = 0
    var tmrRun: NSTimer?

    @IBAction func startRunnng(sender: UIButton)
    {
        tmrRun = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        btnGo.userInteractionEnabled = false
        btnStop.userInteractionEnabled = true
        sliSpeed.userInteractionEnabled = false
    }

    @IBAction func stopRunnng(sender: UIButton)
    {
        [tmrRun invalidate]
        btnGo.userInteractionEnabled = true
        btnStop.userInteractionEnabled = false
        sliSpeed.userInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    func takeABound() -> ()
    {
        pic += 1;
        if (pic == 8){
            pic = 0;
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        pic = 0;
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know much swift, but have you tried tmrRun.invalidate()?

Comment: Thanks for that, it didn't work, but the debugger then suggested tmrRun!.invalidate()  instead and it now runs, but still no scrolling of images for the running wolf.

Comment: Your timer is declared as an Optional, so `tmrRun!.invalidate()` is correct.

Comment: It looks like you want `takeABound` to update the picture, but nothing calls it. Also, the timer is going to call `update`, but you haven't included it.

Comment: I've been trying but without success.  I keep on receiving errors such as cannot convert UIImage.type to UIImage.

Comment: So I am trying to load  the image and then advance to the next frame      func takeABound() -> ()
        {
            String.imageName = [String.stringWithFormat, "\(imvWolf)", pic];
            self.imvWolf.image = [UIImage imageNamed.imageName];
                pic += 1;
            if (pic == 8){
                pic = 0;
            }

Answer (score 0):

To stop the timer is definitely `timername.invalidate()`, but remember you have to also stop the animation:

```
timername.invalidate()
isAnimating = false
```

If doing this you still have issues I think the problem it's where you're typing it.

Try it using this code:

```
@IBAction func playButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    moveWolf()
}
@IBAction func pauseButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    timername.invalidate()
    isAnimating = false
}

func moveWolf(){
    //Here instead of 0.1 you set the slider value
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: Selector("doAnimation"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        isAnimating = true
}

func doAnimation(){
    if counter == 5 {
        counter = 1
    }
    else{
        counter++
    }
    imatge.image = UIImage(named: "picture\(counter).png")
}
```

Hope that helps you! Good luck!